# How to attach a web provisioned event receiver to a web template?

Tags: event-receivers, web-template

I have created a web template using the onet.xml and elements.xml. I have created a web provisioned event receiver, but it is not really attached to my custom web template. When I create a site the web event receiver will fire on every template, like: Team, Blank, etc. How can I attach it to fire only on my custom web template?

Answer (score 0):

In your event receiver code you can check `SPWeb.WebTemplate` and decide whether the new web is being created using your custom template. If it is then you can apply your modifications to the web.
For example:

```
void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
{
    if(properties.Web.WebTemplate =="Your template"){
     //do stuff
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am going to give it a try. I will get back to you soon.

Comment: I tried it, but the `properties.Web.WebTemplate` returns the base template which is STS and not my custom template which is {guid}#templatename. How can I distinguish between my custom template and the other templates, like team site which has the same base template?

Comment: read this article if you are still stuck - search for the word "bag" on the page and start reading from there.http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx